# Application crash on SD card removal

Tags: java, android, memory, android-sdcard

My application has **android:installLocation="preferExternal"** . After the application has been installed and launched , the background services of app gets initiated. When I hard remove the SD card , the application gets crashed giving the **"ClassNotFoundException"** for the application class (which extend android.app.application) .

Following is the error log:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.sample.MyApplication:        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sample.MyApplication in loader  dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/mnt/asec/com.com.sample-1/pkg.apk]

How could this be handled in such a way that the crash can be avoided?

Comment: Seems to be rather obvious to me. If you remove the card from which your application is running, how should it continue? The application is not loaded to memory as a whole while running.

Comment: you are removing media where all the files for running that application has been installed, isn't is obvious it will crash?

Comment: just move your app to phone from setting then try again..

Answer (score 0):

I think the app you use that stores the data in the External Storage SD card ,that what the app crash I think.and even the app has been installed in the SD card i think and while to try to retrieve the data your app crashes...

Instead try to move the app from SD card to phone memory by going to setting of the app

Answer (score 0):

If you declare "preferExternal", you request that your application be installed on the external storage, but the system does not guarantee that your application will be installed on the external storage. If the external storage is full, the system will install it on the internal storage. The user can also move your application between the two locations.

If you declare "auto", you indicate that your application may be installed on the external storage, but you don't have a preference of install location. The system will decide where to install your application based on several factors. The user can also move your application between the two locations.
[Source](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html)